# Как расчитать абсолютную погрешность

Tags: математика

Как мне расчитать абсолютную погрешность, если истинное значение у меня равно нулю. Я расчитываю точность методов нахождения экстремумов функции и истинное значение функции(x*cos(x)*sin(x)) = 0, как тогда считать если на ноль не делится?

Comment: Делить на ноль - это для *относительной* погрешности, а не абсолютной.

Answer (score 0):

Абсюлютная погрешность вычисляется как разница между измерением и истинным значением.  Делить не требуется.

Comment: я перепутал, нужно расчитать относительную погрешность, это возможно с нулём?

Comment: Невозможно, да и смысла нет большого. В метрологии для точки ноль говорят о вариации, например.